# Spring boot: Exclude auto configuration based on environment variable

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

In spring boot we may exclude specific auto-configuration classes such that they will never be applied. Example with annotation based configuration:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = OneConfiguration.class)
```

What I want is to provide an environment variable with a value that will determine some auto configurations that will be excluded. Any ideas how to achieve that?

Comment: I'm sorry, but you can't... The value for annotation attribute SpringBootApplication.exclude must be a class literal.

Comment: 10x! I'll experiment with custom TypeFilter later and write back. I also tried with the exclusion property - spring.autoconfigure.exclude - but it can't be evaluated with SpEL.

Comment: @LachezarBalev I don't understand why `spring.autoconfigure.exclude` is not enough for you. Can you explain more to that? What is the thing about SpEL?

Comment: @er-han here is an explanation - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/11218

Answer (score 13):

You can exclude this configuration class by default:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = OneConfiguration.class)
```

then extend it and make it conditonal:

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "one.configuration.condtion", havingValue = "some-value")
public class OneConfigurationConditional extends OneConfiguration { }
```

Answer (score 2):

Create class extending `Condition` checking value of enviroment variable:

```
public class AutoConfigurationCondition extends Condition {

    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
        return System.getenv("EXCLUDE").equals("yes");
     }
}
```

Then you can use it in `Configuration` class:

```
@Configuration
@Conditional(AutoConfigurationCondition.class)
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {OneConfiguration.class})
class AutoConfigurationExcludingConf {}
```

Comment: I'm afraid that this will not work, because @EnableAutoConfiguration should be used only once (according to the docs). And what I want is to be able to dynamically swap between two auto configurations. In reality I want to choose between two JMS providers - ActiveMQ or ArtemisMQ which are available as starters. The app is deployed in several different environments. Maybe I may use profiles, although I'm not very keen on that.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to do what I wanted with profiles :-( So I have few files now - e.g. `application-artemis.yaml` and `application-activemq.yaml`. In each I've defined corresponding `spring.autoconfigure.exclude` [property](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-auto-configuration.html). I'm not proud with this solution though it works fine so far and looks more or less neat compared to other things that I did :-) .

What I've tried besides that:

1. Managing the value with an environment variable, e.g.:

> ```
> spring:
>   autoconfigure:
>     exclude: ${ABC:com.example.Myautoconfiguration}
> ```

This does not work and I've even reported it as an [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/11218). But it seems that I can't rely on expression for this property. Strange enough it works for other properties...

2. I've played around with the suggestion of @Randal Flagg but somehow I couldn't get it up and running - I'm using `@SpringBootApplication`, the documentation says that I can use EnableAutoConfiguration only once, etc.
3. I've tried with my own `TypeFilter` but this is also not an option - autoconfigurations have special treatment during component scan and the design does not seem very extensible there. At least I could not find a nice way to plug in.